# GMainLoop and TCP Listen thread blocking

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, tcp, glib

I need your help.

I've got main loop GMainLoop with attached timeout callback:

```
MainLoop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);
g_timeout_add_seconds(Interval, TimeoutCallback, (gpointer) Rec);
g_main_loop_run(MainLoop);
```

And listen socket:

```
int ControlServer::GStart()
 {
   int listenfd;
   GIOChannel *in;
   socklen_t addr_len;
   listenfd = TcpListen(host, port, &addr_len);
   in = g_io_channel_unix_new(listenfd);
   g_io_add_watch(in, G_IO_IN, (GIOFunc) Handler, (gpointer) Rec);
   g_io_channel_unref(in);
   return 0;
 }
```

All's good and timeout function work properly until any client not connected to listened socket. After connection, timeout not working all time that client connected. I think it's connected with threads as by GLib documentation in default GMainContext all actions executing in one thread. And I modified code with this:

```
int ControlServer::GThStart()
 {
  int listenfd;
  socklen_t addr_len;
  GIOChannel *Channel;
  GSource *Source;
  GMainContext *Context;

  listenfd = TcpListen(host, port, &addr_len);
  Channel = g_io_channel_unix_new(listenfd);
  Source = g_io_create_watch(Channel, G_IO_IN);
  g_source_set_callback(Source, (GSourceFunc) Handler, (gpointer) Rec, NULL);
  Context = g_main_context_new();
  g_source_attach(Source, Context);
  g_source_unref(Source);
  return 0;
}
```

But now socket is listened but no any clients can connect to it and Handler function never called.

Handler code is below:

```
bool ControlServer::Handler(GIOChannel *in, GIOCondition condition, gpointer data)
 {
   Recorder *Rec = (Recorder *) data;
   struct sockaddr_storage income;
   int insock, newsock;
   socklen_t income_len;
   struct sockaddr peer;
   socklen_t size;
   Access *access;

   insock = g_io_channel_unix_get_fd(in);
   income_len = sizeof(income);
   newsock = accept(insock, (struct sockaddr *) &income, &income_len);
   size = sizeof(peer);
   getpeername(newsock, &peer, &size);
   struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *) &peer;
   access = new Access(newsock, ipv4, MAXN);

   access->Cycle(Rec);

   delete access;
   return true;
}
```

Class 'Access' check client's rights and executing protocol exchange by implementation infinite cycle while client or server not close connection.

```
  do
    {
      result = DoCycle(Rec);
      sprintf(str, "DEBUG: DoCycle(Rec) returns '%d'\n", result);
      AppendLog(str, class_name, DEBUG);
    } while (result != -1);
```

DoCycle() returns '-1' only when connection closed or error exchanging data over TCP.

What are wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: What does Handler look like?

Comment: I just now add code for Handler and some explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in function `int ControlServer::GThStart()`, you should add the `GSource` to the `GMainContext` of your `GMainLoop`, not to new context, try it with:

```
g_source_attach(Source,g_main_loop_get_context(MainLoop));
```